# OpenCL on NVIDIA GTX670M

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia

I write a C++ application on Win64 using OpenCL. I downloaded CUDA SDK 4.2 and installed OpenCL.lib in my lib directory. In the first invocation of OpenCL:

```
    cl_uint n = 0;
    cl_int err = ::clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &n);
```

my application goes down ( with system fatal error ). Does somebody have the same problem on NVIDIA GTX670M? How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Be more specific. What OS and what version of the CUDA SDK?